# deleting last char in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define ROZ 100
char *deleteLastChar(char* s)
{
    int rozmiar,i;
    char *tab1;

    rozmiar=strlen(s);
    tab1=(char*)malloc((rozmiar-1)*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<(rozmiar-1); i++)
    {
        tab1[i]=s[i];
    }
    return tab1;
    free(s);
}



main()
{
    char tab1[ROZ], *tab2;
    int l,i,p,a;

    printf("podaj napis\n");

    fgets(tab1, 100, stdin);

    l=strlen(tab1);     
    tab2=malloc(l*sizeof(int));
    if (tab2==NULL)
        printf("blad");
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        tab2 = deleteLastChar(tab2);
        p = strlen(tab2);
        for(a=0;a<p;a++)
        {
            printf("%c",tab2[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hi
I'm trying to make a program which is deleting the last char from string over and over again until there is no more chars in it. It has to be done on dynamic arrays by shortening new arrray and rewrite previous array into it. Program is compiling without any errors, although it doesn't work as it suppouse to do. After putting an input it is outputting "e" multiple times.

Comment: This looks suspicious:`tab2=(char*)malloc(l*sizeof(int));` and `tab1=(char*)malloc((rozmiar-1)*sizeof(int));`. Also,you pass uninitialized `tab2` as a parameter to function `deleteLastChar()` and try to store the length of it in `rozmiar`.

Comment: `main` w/o return type most certainly isn't valid C11.

Comment: and `free(s)` is unreachable. You shouldn't continue if `tab2==NULL`.

Comment: Ok, I just realize I forgot to rewrite first tab1 static array into tab2 dynamic array. But still it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lot of errors

1. You allocate extra space for the input string copy, you should not multiply by `sizeof(int)` because you need `l` `char`s not `l` `int`s, and that's partially true, because you also need the `'\0'` terminating character, so you need `1 + l` `char`s, hence the first malloc line should read

   ```
   tab2 = malloc(1 + l);
   ```
2. You check the success of `malloc` but still continue to dereference a potentially `NULL` pointer, it doesn't matter what you do in case of `malloc` failure but you cannot derefrence a `NULL` pointer, this

   ```
   if (tab2 == NULL)
      printf("blad");
   ```

   should be something like

   ```
   if (tab2 == NULL)
      return -1; /* or anything that will abort execution */
   ```
3. You never copy the data read via `fgets()` to the newly allocated buffer, you should copy the bytes to the `tab2`.

   ```
   strcpy(tab2, tab1);
   ```
4. You don't add a terminating null byte after copying the characters in the `deleteLastChar()` function. You must add

   ```
   tab1[rozmiar - 1] = '\0';
   ```

   at the end of the `for` loop in `deleteLastChar()`.
5. You `free` `s` in the `deleteLastChar()` function, after return, that line will never be reached, so it doesn't make sense, also you should not `free` that, because it's an input parameter to `deleteLastChar()` you should do it in the caller function instead.

This is a copy of your code, fixed

```
char *deleteLastChar(char* s)
{
    int rozmiar,i;
    char *tab1;

    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;
    rozmiar = strlen(s);
    if(rozmiar == 0)
        return NULL;
    tab1 = malloc(rozmiar);
    if (tab1 == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0 ; i < (rozmiar - 1) ; i++)
    {
        tab1[i] = s[i];
    }
    tab1[rozmiar - 1] = '\0';

    return tab1;
}


int main()
{
    char tab1[ROZ], *tab2;
    int l, i, p, a;

    printf("podaj napis\n");

    fgets(tab1, 100, stdin);

    l    = strlen(tab1);
    tab2 = malloc(1 + l);
    if (tab2 == NULL)
        return -1;
    strcpy(tab2, tab1);

    for (i = 0 ; i < l ; i++)
    {
        char *result;

        result = deleteLastChar(tab2);
        if (tab2 != NULL)
        {
            p = strlen(tab2);
            for (a = 0 ; a < p ; a++)
            {
                printf("%c", tab2[a]);
            }
            free(tab2);
            printf("\n");

            tab2 = result;
        }
        else
        {
            free(tab2);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    free(tab2);

    return 0;
}
```

BTW, doesn't it look more readable with the use of more whitespace?

**Note**: Oh, and there is no need to cast `malloc` in c, and `fgets()` consumes the trailing `'\n'`, so you might want to remove that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Right away I can see 2 issues with your code

- You are passing tab2 to deleteLastChar. tab2 is just allocated, data is not assigned to tab2. I think your intension is to pass tab1
- There is no point in calling free() after return statement in deleteLastChar()